# Pressing Enter on GTK Entry to activate a button

Tags: rust, gtk

I have a GTK Entry called `task_input`. When the user types something and presses enter, it should "click" `start_button`. I have tried using `connect_activate`, which works, but it leaves me with the following error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: 01:04:12.779: GtkText - did not receive a focus-out event.
If you handle this event, you must return
GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE so the default handler
gets the event as well
```

Here is the code:

```
fn setup_settings(&self) {
    let imp = imp::MyWindow::from_instance(self);

    imp.task_input.connect_activate(clone!(@strong imp.start_button as start => move |_| {
        start.emit_clicked();
    }));
}
```

I believe there is also another way to do this by using `imp.task_input.set_activates_default(true);` but I have not been able to figure out how to get that to work.

What is the best way to activate a button by pressing `Enter` from an Entry widget?

Comment: Which version of GTK?

Comment: Assuming GTK 4, when you tried the `set_activates_default` approach, did you call [`set_default_widget`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.GtkWindowExt.html#tymethod.set_default_widget) to tell the Window which button is the default?

Comment: I did try to `set_default_widget` but I kept getting errors when using `self.set_default_widget` while working in `window.rs`. I will work more on this approach and see if I can get it. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @cdhowie I was able to use `set_default_widget`. It turns out it wasn't working because I was using `imp.start_button`. I made a clone of that and it worked. However, I still get the same `Gtk-WARNING` I posted above. Any ideas how I can get rid of that?